# How to check if property 'isElementContentWhitespace' is supported?

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to use [isElementContentWhitespace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/text.isElementContentWhitespace) on text nodes, 
but not all browsers support it, so I need to check if its supported,
then if is, use it, if not implement jquery's $.trim...

i've tried doing something like this with no luck on IE, good on FF:

```
var testEl = document.createElement('span');  
testEl.innerHTML = ' ';  
alert( testEl.firstChild.isElementContentWhitespace );
```

Comment: what exactly does "with no luck" mean?

Comment: Why not just use trim in all cases? 

`var iswhitespace = (testEl.innerHTML == testEl.innerHTML.trim())`

Comment: wouldn't that be `testEl.innerHtml.trim() == ""`. if innerHtml equals innerHtml.trim, that just says that the value does not have whitespace surrounding the content (it'd be true, say, for the value "abc")

Comment: Yep, nice catch: `var iswhitespace = ('' == testEl.innerHTML.trim())`

Comment: I don't want to use Trim because its not native and has to process the text every time, whereas isElementContentWhitespace exists already.. (for some browsers)

Comment: isWhitespace has a different meaning to isElementContentWhitespace.

Comment: What are you going to do with the textnode if isElementContentWhitespace returns true? If you already are using JQuery, why avoid using the trim function they provide? Regardless of whether or not it's native, it's tested to work in many browsers, and the time it takes to trim is negligible.

Comment: I don't want to rely no the slightest bit of code that "might" fail someday, if I could use a native one instead. I need this because I'm searching text in the document tree and I don't want to go inside a node that is empty or has whitespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Test if any Property is available for a DOM element like so:

```js
var textNode = document.createTextNode('text');  
console.log( 'isElementContentWhitespace' in textNode );
```

> Note that `isElementContentWhitespace` is **Obsolete**

Comment: Yep, this is it. Don't expect all the whitespace nodes in the document to be `isElementContentWhitespace` though, it only applies when the parent Element is defined as containing only other elements, not MIXED content. So eg. a whitespace-only TextNode inside `<div>` will never set `isElementContentWhitespace` true. The MDC page's description of the property is a little misleading.

Comment: well, this is certainly a bummer. its super important what you just said, but I never have read it nowhere. good to have these things written here.